# Problem with geolocation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I have developed a simple program for current user location following this tutorial : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNMNRAbIDoU

However when I build and run, the map is shown but the cuppertino location (apple headquarters) is not located on the map.

I heard that the problem may be that apple didn't recognize my wifi or something like that, is this possible, and if so, should I keep my code and suppose it to be true and so wait to test it on device later? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you watch to the end of the tutorial as he makes a mistake on the method name, which he corrects, to be honest it doesn't look like a very good tutorial, I'd find another.

Answer (score 0):

In Simulator, the blue dot will always pinpoint the Mothership.

However, mapView.userLocation.coordinate will in fact return your current location coordinate (based on Wifi, so be sure it's on).

Note, though, in pre-4.0, mapView.userLocation.coordinate is returns the coordinates for the Mothership.

Once you start testing on your device the blue dot will appear correctly in your MKMapView. Be sure to test your app on a device when using CLLocation and MKMapView, especially if you rely on the users location for anything. Well, always be sure to test your app on a device :)

Comment: and if the blue dot doesn't pinpoint, does that mean my code has something wrong ??